# How to expose a remote controller

Tags: spring

I need help at Spring

I want to send request on the remote controller (http://123.123.123.123/vehicles/all)...

example..

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/vehicles")
public class AutoController {

    AutoService autoserv;

    @Autowired
    public AutoController(AutoService autoserv) {
        this.autoserv = autoserv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/all")
    public Result<Car> all() {
        List<Car> autlst = autoserv.getAuto();
        return new Result<Car>(autlst);
    }
}
```

from my a local application and get response List..
How does that..? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean "remote controller" instead of "remove controller"? Are you asking about how to do (say) a web service call from one web application to another, running on different containers/servers?

Comment: What do you mean by "get response List"?

Comment: "Do you mean "remote controller" instead of "remove controller"? Are you asking about how to do (say) a web service call from one web application to another, running on different containers/servers? – nickdos " ....          Yes..                                                                 "What do you mean by "get response List"?"..                               I want to get "List<Car>" from one web application to another...            Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to implement RESTful Webservices?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer

If this is the case have a look on the following pages to get you started:

http://www.stupidjavatricks.com/?p=54

http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=544

Comment: Ок.. I am much obliged to you!  TYVM

Comment: When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you're getting value from the community.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just add to chzbrgla's excellent answer, that you might want to consider using JSON for the serialization (as opposed to XML), depending on your requirements - JSON is more light-weight and easier to parse (debatable) but maybe less type-safe.

It's very easy to get Spring-MVC 3.0 to automagically produce both XML & JSON output:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multiple-representations

To access the JSON version of a page, simply append ".json" to the URI (or set the appropriate HTTP request header - `accept:"application/json"`).

To consume JSON, you will need to:

- make a HTTP GET request to your remote webapp (suggest [Apache Commons HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/))
- parse the resulting JSON string (suggest [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), which is what Spring uses to create the JSON) to generate your `List<Car>`